# How to create mosaic plot from Pandas dataframe with Statsmodels library?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Using Python 3.4, Pandas 0.15 and Statsmodels 0.6.0, I try to create a [mosaic plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_plot) from a dataframe as described in the [Statsmodels documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot.mosaic.html). However, I just don't understand how the input has to be formatted that is provided to the `mosaic()` function.

Given a simple dataframe:

```
In:
myDataframe = pd.DataFrame({'size' : ['small', 'large', 'large', 'small', 'large', 'small'], 'length' : ['long', 'short', 'short', 'long', 'long', 'short']})

Out:
  length   size
0   long  small
1  short  large
2  short  large
3   long  small
4   long  large
5  short  small
```

When trying to create a mosaic plot of this data:

```
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
mosaic(data=myDataframe, title='Mosaic Plot')
```

gives `ValueError: cannot label index with a null key`

As mosaic plots are a visualization of contingency tables, I tried to create such first with

```
In:
myCrosstable = pd.crosstab(myDataframe['size'], myDataframe['length'])

Out:
length  long  short
size               
large      1      2
small      2      1
```

Still, using `myCrosstable` as data argument gives the same error.

How does the dataframe have to be formatted in order to get accepted by the `mosaic()` function? The documentation says as explanation for the data argument:
Parameters:

> data : dict, pandas.Series, np.ndarray, pandas.DataFrame
>
> ```
> The contingency table that contains the data. Each category should contain a non-negative number with a tuple as index.
> ```

Isn't that what the `pd.crosstab` function returns? If not, how can I convert the dataframe accordingly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I used your data and this code:

```
mosaic(myDataframe, ['size', 'length'])
```

and got the chart like this:

[image: mosaic chart]

Comment: Hi, how would i make it so that the boxes are based on another column's values?

Comment: @user147529 - Second argument to `mosaic` is the list of columns you want to use to size the boxes. If this doesn't help - perhaps try a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the stack function on the crosstab to avoid recomputing the contingency table.

With your code, `mosaic(myCrossTable.stack())` works.